# How to get the ID of a sent notification using Expo SDK?

Tags: react-native, expo

## Edit

As a (hopefully) temporary workaround, I add the chat message ID, that the notification is associated with, into [`data`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#usage), then once the user receives it in the [`task`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438632/2891356), I make a request to my backend, sending along the notification ID, along with the chat message ID, and store it in my database. Not the most ideal solution, because if a source user sends a message to a target user and then decides to instantly delete it, then I won't be able to dismiss the notification that was sent out to the target user if the target user doesn't have the app active.

---

I'm using [expo-server-sdk-node](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node?tab=readme-ov-file#expo-server-sdk-node--) to send out notifications programmatically on my backend.

For each successfully sent out notification, I get a receipt ID, which, as it turns out, isn't the same as the ID of the notification itself.

A receipt ID is a regular uuid, whereas a notification ID resembles the following format:

```
0:1703170688617238%397189adf9fd7ecd
```

Therefore, attempting to delete the notification with [`dismissNotificationAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#dismissnotificationasyncnotificationidentifier) would not work.

Any ideas on how to retrieve the actual ID of the notification?

Comment: I believe the solution you found is the only viable solution. You mentioned a problem about the sender deleting the message, but you can get around that by just keeping the ids of recently deleted messages on your backend.

Comment: Right, but how how can I delete the notification that is associated with that deleted chat message from the target user's notification tray? If the source user exits and closes the app from recent apps, they would receive the notification and then it would just stay in the notification tray, because nothing I can do can delete that notification

Comment: React Native has headless mode that can be used to handle notifications. I used it outside of expo, so idk how expo configures it, but maybe it is enabled by default. Anyway my point is that you can still work with notifications even if the user closes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here are two approaches that are documented nowhere that are viable solutions to my (and you, the future reader's) problem.

#### First approach:

When you send out a notification for a chat message, associate its unique ID in the notification's [`data`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#usage) prop. Then, if a a source user sends a target user a chat message and then decides to delete it, if the target user is offline and the app is exited, send out another notification to the target user, also attaching the deleted message's unique ID with it, and then use [`getPresentedNotificationsAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#getpresentednotificationsasync) in [`registerTaskAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#registertaskasynctaskname) to receive a list object containing [`Notification[]`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notification). In each notification, you'll be able to access [`identifier`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notificationrequest), which you can use with [`dismissNotificationAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#dismissnotificationasyncnotificationidentifier) to remove it. Also, don't forget to use `dismissNotificationAsync` to remove the notification that you just sent to the offline target user after the source user decided to delete his message that he sent to the target user.

#### Second approach:

I ended up using this one.

Also working with `registerTaskAsync` as in the first approach, we save every incoming notification into our SQLLite database, creating a record containing the notification ID and the chat message ID that it is associated with. Taking the use case from the first approach, if a source user decides to delete a chat message, and the target user is offline, we send out a notification with the deleted chat message ID to the offline target user (again, just like in the first approach). In our background task, we then parse the incoming "deletion" notification, pluck the deleted chat message's ID, and then `select` from our database the record that is associated with that chat message ID. We then use the notification ID of that record to remove the notification with `dismissNotificationAsync` and, just as above, we also use `dismissNotificationAsync` to delete the "deletion" notification, which we just sent out to the offline target user.

Obviously none of these problems exist if the the target user is online and the app is open, foregrounded or backgrounded, but in such a situation, these two options were the only ones that I was able to come up with.